# Retrofit response return null in onResponse function (single JSON object)

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit, slim-3

I'm try to get response from retrofit API after register the user.

I get null from `response.body()` function

Register URL: https://apitest10101.000webhostapp.com/alaa-apii/public/createuser (Method POST)

The API return single object JSON like

```
{
    "error": true,
    "message": "User Already Exists"
}
```

[image]"response work after tested in postman"

**RegisterActivity.java**

```
public void register(View view) {

       if(Validate())
       {
           Log.d("####", "OKAAAAAY");

            first_name = first_name_edit.getText().toString().trim();
            last_name = last_name_edit.getText().toString().trim();
            email = email_edit.getText().toString().trim();
            password = password_edit.getText().toString().trim();
            phone = Integer.parseInt(phone_edit.getText().toString().trim());
            state = state_edit.getText().toString().trim();
            block = block_edit.getText().toString().trim();
            street = street_edit.getText().toString().trim();
            building = buidling_edit.getText().toString().trim();
            floor = floor_edit.getText().toString().trim();
            flat = flat_edit.getText().toString().trim();


          Call<ResultModel> call = RetrofitClient
                .getInstance()
                .getApi()
                .createUser(first_name, last_name, email, password, phone, postionOfReigon, state, block, street, building, floor, flat);

          call.enqueue(new Callback<ResultModel>() {
              @Override
              public void onResponse(Call<ResultModel> call, Response<ResultModel> response) {

                  boolean error = false;
                  String mass = null;
                  if (response.body() != null) { // response null  !!!!!!!!!!!
                      error = response.body().getError();
                      mass = response.body().getMessage();
                      Log.d("#####", error + "------" + mass);
                  }


                      Log.d("#####", error + "------" + mass);

              }

              @Override
              public void onFailure(Call<ResultModel> call, Throwable t) {
                  Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              }
          });


       }
       else
       {
           Log.d("####", "NNNOOTT OKAAAAAY");
       }

    }
```

If I remove if statement in `response.body()` I got this error in log

```
2019-11-10 12:45:51.242 21211-21211/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 21211
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Boolean com.example.myapplication.ResultModel.getError()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplication.RegisterActivity$2.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:161)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:83)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

**ResultModel.java**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ResultModel {

    @SerializedName("error")
    @Expose
    private Boolean error;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    public ResultModel(Boolean error, String message) {
        this.error = error;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Boolean getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(Boolean error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

**RetrofitClient.java**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {

    private  static final String BASE_URL = "https://apitest10101.000webhostapp.com/alaa-apii/public/";
    private static RetrofitClient mInstance;
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    private RetrofitClient(){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance()
    {
        if(mInstance == null)
        {
            mInstance = new RetrofitClient();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public Api getApi()
    {
        return retrofit.create(Api.class);
    }



}
```

**API interface**

```
package com.example.myapplication;


import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface Api {


    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("createuser")
    Call<ResultModel> createUser(
            @Field("firstname") String firstname,
            @Field("lastname") String lastname,
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("password") String password,
            @Field("phone") int phone,
            @Field("region") int region,
            @Field("state") String state,
            @Field("block") String block,
            @Field("street") String street,
            @Field("building") String building,
            @Field("floor") String floor,
            @Field("flat") String flat
    );
}
```

**build gradle**

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.2'
```

the `getError()` should return false or true and the `getMessage()`
should return the message **User Already Exists** or **User created successfully** .

I use slim framework v3.12 to build api.

** Any suggest **

Comment: seems like you have already registered the user in the backend, so you are getting this response

Comment: Can you please confirm that your URL is complete? Also, can you please confirm your HTTP response code?

Comment: Yes I want to read this response in android using ```response.body()``` but is return null

Comment: @SWAT10101 Also, please check the contents for the `Response` object by debugging. You may get clues there as well.

Comment: @Shankha057 the user registered in database but if I want to re register again with same email I should get message in response body It work well in postman when I test the api.

Comment: @SWAT10101 that's true, but what about the full URL that you pass to `Retrofit`? I mean the place where you set your `baseUrl`, have you set your `baseUrl` correctly? Also, please debug and check the `Response` object itself and find out about the actual response code.

Comment: @Shankha057 yes sorry I forget to add retrofit object initialize I well added now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you're getting `422` as http status. Everything that is not a `2XX` status code is treated as an error by retrofit and in such cases you access it using `response.errorBody()`.

The not so great news is that it has to be manually converted. One way to do this is using `response.errorBody().string()`.

Make sure you call it only once as after the first read it'll no longer be readable. It's a stream like behaviour.

Comment: It work fine but I want to get error as an object. ```  if(response.code() == 422)
                  {
                   
                      try {
                          Log.d("#####", response.errorBody().string() + "");
                      }
                      catch (IOException e)
                      {
                          Log.d("#####", e.getMessage() + "");
                      }
                      
**output** ```  {"error":true,"message":"User Already Exists"}```

Answer (score 1):

The response code you are getting is 422, if this code is agreed upon by the back-end and the front-end that this is not an error, then there is a solution you can do by creating a custom `Interceptor` and letting it still return the response you get when you get that response code, just make sure to add the `Interceptor` to your `Retrofit client`

Comment: what this solution does is that it allows retrofit to read the 422 response code as a success and not a failed request which will then allow it to be parsed by your code correctly